# Django Unique model for every user

Tags: python, django

How do I create a new model for every user in django. Like a new list of items for every new user

Comment: You should write What you have tried yet ? If you are stuck we are ready to help. [Read How to ask a question on Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

That is not something you should do.

> A model is the single, **definitive** source of information about your
>   data.

This implies that the model can't be different for every single entity (the user in this case) in your app. A **definitive** source for your data should not have to be *unique* for every user.

For more on Django models: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/